# Why is $\frac{d f(g(h(x)))}{d x} = \frac{d f(g(h(x)))}{d h(x)}\frac{d h(x)}{d x}$, not $\frac{d f(g(h(x)))}{d g(h(x)))}\frac{d h(x)}{d x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

According to the chain rule $(f(g(x))' = f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

I would have thought the latter would be correct, since I would identify $g(x)$ with $g(h(x))$ in my question title.

Comment: If you proceed as you prefer, the result would be $\frac{d f(g(h(x)))}{d g(h(x)))}\frac{dg(h(x))}{d x}$, which is **also** correct. Two different ways to use the chain rule: between $f\circ g$ and $h$, or between $f $ and $g\circ h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define a composite function as $(f\circ g \circ h)(x)$ we have two ways of interpreting it:

1. $((f \circ g)\circ h)(x)$
2. $(f \circ (g\circ h))(x)$

These are identical, and if we apply the chain rule we get:

1'. $(f\circ g)'h(x)\cdot h'(x)$

2'. $f'(g\circ h)(x)\cdot (g \circ h)'(x)$

The next step brings the two together:

$f'(g(h(x)))\cdot g'(h(x))\cdot h'(x)$

Comment: Ah, I missed that I should identify the outer part with $f$. Am I right with the observation that the notation $(f(g(x)))' = f'(g(x))g'(x)$ completely obscures that $f'(g(x))$ is the derivative of $f$ wrt. $g(x)$ (not wrt. $x$).

Comment: i always work backwards dh, dg, df